# Serverless add assumed role to allow cloudwatch to call lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to allow cloudwatch to execute a lambda function in a serverless.yml. I can do this via the CLI. How can I do this within a serverless.yml?

CLI command [from here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html):

`aws lambda add-permission --function-name XXX --statement-id MyId --action 'lambda:InvokeFunction' --principal events.amazonaws.com --source-arn arn:aws:events:us-east-1:1232132323:rule/XXXX`

I tried [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55026399/allow-serverless-lambda-to-be-called-by-cloud-watch) which immediately gave deployment errors:

```
functions:
  generateFile:
    handler: api/handler.generateFile
    tags:
      LiveOrTest: test
# to allow cloudwatch to invoke lambdas
resources:
  Resources:
    cleanLambdaPermission:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      Properties:
        FunctionName:
          "Fn::GetAtt": [cleanLambdaFunction, Arn]
        Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        Principal: "events.amazonaws.com"
        SourceArn: "*"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only apparent issue in your `AWS::Lambda::Permission` is **incorrect ARN**:

```
SourceArn: "*"
```

You can't have `*` as ARN, instead it should be:

```
SourceArn: "arn:aws:events:us-east-1:1232132323:rule/XXXX"
```

Alternatively, you can just **remove** the entire `SourceArn` property.

Comment: is there a way to make this generic ie apply to all lambdas, not just "cleanLambdaFunction"?

Comment: @Rilcon42 Sadly there is not. This is resource-based policy attached to an individual function. Its similar to bucket policy for a bucket.